# how to configure multiple AWS profiles in AWS code build buildspec file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild, aws-devops

I am trying to provision AWS services in multiple accounts (Same organization), using Terraform, Codebuild, Codecommit and Codepipeline. How to configure **multiple named profiles** (AWS Configure) in buildspec file? Is there any other workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

> multiple named profiles (AWS Configure) in buildspec file

This is not a good idea. Usually you allow for cross-account access using [cross-account IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html). So in your case, your CB script would assume IAM roles for different accounts so that it can interact with them.

Comment: how terraform will understand the respective account. more precisely we need to specify alias in the provider block.